# Why is firefox private window sending a cookie?

Tags: firefox, http

I was tracing with wireshark and started a private window with firefox.  I am wondering why there is a cookie being sent in the GET request as so

```
GET http://www.colorado.edu/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.colorado.edu
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: f5_persistence=3037767872.20480.0000
Connection: keep-alive
```

anyone happen to now why?

EDIT: just for grins, chrome incognito window sends cookies too...

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.colorado.edu
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.86 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: f5_persistence=3037767872.20480.0000; has_js=1; __utma=72446465.1575989719.1462319715.1462319715.1462319715.1; __utmb=72446465.7.10.1462319715; __utmc=72446465; __utmz=72446465.1462319715.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
If-None-Match: "1462320046-0"
```

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behaviour for checking for authentication or tracking cookies.

Running in private/incognito mode does not prevent sites from sending or using cookies for your session. What these browsing modes actually do is present your session to the website as a brand new, never before seen user.

Being a "new" user, the website will just treat you just the same as a genuine new user. The conversation between the devices would go something like this:

> **SERVER:** Hi, have you been here before?
>
> **YOUR PC:** Nope, never.
>
> **SERVER:** OK, well have this cookie so I can follow the crumbs you leave behind as you travel my links!
>
> **YOUR PC:** OK, sure.
>
> **YOU CLOSE AND REOPEN THE BROWSER**
>
> **SERVER:** Hi, have you been here before?
>
> **YOUR PC:** Nope, never.
>
> etc, etc...

When you exit the browser all the cookies you have received are securely deleted.